# Why isn't 'half' an adjective in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, phrases

The following example is from [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/dilbilgisi/ingiliz-dilbilgisi/adverb-phrases):

> A: Want some sugar in your coffee?
>
> B: Only half a spoon, please

They categorise 'only' as an adverb phrase, which I agree with; however, they consider 'half' as a word that modifies the adverb. I'm of the opinion that 'half' modifies, or describes 'spoon'. So why isn't 'half' an adjective that describes 'spoon' in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider "half" an adjective that modifies "spoon". However, be aware that a determiner is usually the first element in a noun phrase, so it is unusual to put "half" before "a". You'd have to consider this an idiomatic construction.

Another interpretation is also possible: that the word "of" has been omitted. Therefore, the complete phrase would be "only half of a spoon".

You may be interested in the answers to these questions:
["More than half" or "More than half of"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93776/more-than-half-or-more-than-half-of)
["half of pound" or "half of a pound" or "half pound"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168762/half-of-pound-or-half-of-a-pound-or-half-pound)